# how to allow g.drawstring in c# to be adjusted after it is placed in picturebox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, picturebox

I am trying to use a picturebox and pick out 2 points(eyes in a photo). I would pick out the two points with `g.DrawString` where I will draw 2 different 'x'. The problem now is I am stuck as what if the user has placed the 'x' on a wrong position and I would like to adjust it. Is there any codes which will allow the `g.DrawString` 'x' to be able to be moved?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Camera
{
    public partial class CamDisplay : Form
    {

        public CamDisplay()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"C:\center90\center90(1).jpg";
        }


        bool MousedClicked = true;
        bool MouseClicked2 = true;

        private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseClick(e);

            if (MousedClicked == true)
            {
                txtXaxis.Text = e.X.ToString();
                txtYaxis.Text = e.Y.ToString();
                MousedClicked = false;

                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(pictureBox1.Handle))
                {
                    using (Font myFont = new Font("Calibri", 8))
                    {
                        g.DrawString("X", myFont, Brushes.Red, new PointF(e.X, e.Y));
                    }
                }
            }

            else if (MouseClicked2 == true)
            {
                txtRXaxis.Text = e.X.ToString();
                txtRYaxis.Text = e.Y.ToString();
                MouseClicked2 = false;

                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(pictureBox1.Handle))
                {
                    using (Font myFont = new Font("Calibri", 8))
                    {
                        g.DrawString("X", myFont, Brushes.Red, new PointF(e.X, e.Y));
                    }
                }
            }

            else
            {
                MousedClicked = false;
                MouseClicked2 = false;
            }

        }

        private void CamDisplay_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            pictureBox1.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. As I understand your problem you have two options:

1. If you are using your Graphics object to directly manipulate the BMP (ie. you DrawString directly to the bitmap) there is no way to "undo" a previous operation. You could instead keep a local copy of the original bitmap in memory, duplicate it to a second bitmap and perform the operations only on the copy, which is the one you show in your form. When you need to "undo" you just go back to the original copy.
2. Do not manipulate the bitmap directly, but instead perform your drawing operations in the OnPaint() event of the PictureBox. In that way you only draw to the screen, leaving the original Bmp intact. See example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b818z6z6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: i added in my codes is it possible to give me some advice where i should make the changes?

Comment: I'm sorry for the long delay, I've been very busy. From a quick glance at your code it seems you are drawing directly to the window on the mouse click event. That would be a variation on suggestion (2) above. Refreshing the window/control should actually "erase" both marks. Try calling pictureBox1.Refresh().